# How do I convert a single FITS image into Red, Green and Blue images?

Tags: software, astrophotography, file-format

I've been looking for a software to get a FITS file and export 1 file for each of the RED, GREEN and BLUE channels.
I came across Nebulosity last week, but I can't buy it's licence since I live in Iran...
I'll be grateful if you introduce any similar applications...

Comment: I think the requirement to use a specific scientific data file format may move this to being off-topic. But, you might look at ImageMagick, which I believe has support for this format and which definitely can split an image by channel.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific need for results in a scientific data format.

Comment: Thanks a million. I'll try ImageMagick, I saw FITS in supported formats... hope it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Raw Therapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/), it's free.

Almost every other software have this feature, Photoshop, Coral Paint Shop Pro and much more. just pick one.

In Paint Shop Pro You go to:  Image -> Split Channel -> Split to RGB. Simple as that.
In photoshop it should be the same.

**Edit**: Since spliting TIFF format does not help you I suggested an edit to your question.

Comment: I know, but they don't support FITS format.

Comment: I don't know about FITS, but TIFF is definitely being supported in all the 3 softwares I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider FITS Liberator, which is a software developed by NASA and ESA.

It is also free and was built to support a number of astrophoto formats.

It's available here:
http://www.spacetelescope.org/projects/fits_liberator/

Should be available for download for your region.

If you want to buy software, I highly suggest PixInsight.  It's what I use.  Liscensing is based in the EU, so it may still be a challenge for you.

http://pixinsight.com/

Comment: Thank you, well I actually am using FITS Liberator for other purposes and not for dividing the channels. I think what mattdm said can do the job. ImageMagick...